# Investigating whether the series converges uniformly using the Weierstrass M-test.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

I have recently found myself stuck on a question for a long time, unable to get my head around it. It is:

I have to investigate whether the following series converges uniformly

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(lnx)^n}{(x-1)^{2n}}$  on the interval $(3,\infty]$.

I have used the fact that $lnx \le x - 1$ for all $x \ge 1$ to show that $(lnx)^n \le (x-1)^n$ for all $x \ge 1$ but I do not know where to proceed from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{(\ln x)^n}{(x - 1)^{2n}} \leq \frac{(x - 1)^n}{(x - 1)^{2n}} = \frac{1}{(x - 1)^{n}} \leq \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
by our assumption that $x \geq 3$. Now use the $M$ test with $f_n(x) = \frac{(\ln x)^n}{(x - 1)^{2n}}$ and $M_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Using the M test I got that the series of $M_n$ = 1, meaning it is uniformly convergent over the interval as 1 is smaller than infinity, is this right? Thanks!

Comment: @Zombiegit123 Yes this is correct.